# rabbitmq getting message that doesn't match any topic

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new with RabbitMQ and would like to pick up messages that don't match any topic.

Already try to use alternate exchange but the messages that don't match any topic are just getting lost.
Steps I used to create an alternate exchange:

1. create a new exchange with the type fanout and use as an argument: alternate-exchange = eps (eps is the exchange with the topic exchange that normally get the messages)
2. Create the queue for alternative messages
3. add the binding between the exchange and the new queue

Answer (score 0):

You have your configuration the wrong way around: the `alternate-exchange` argument has to be specified on the *existing* exchange, your topic exchange `eps`.

Consider the flow through the system (as [described in the RabbitMQ manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html#how-it-works))

1. Message is published to topic exchange `eps`
2. The `eps` exchange looks to see if any queue bindings match the message's routing key
3. If none match, it checks *its own settings* for an `alternate-exchange`
4. If that exchange exists, it publishes the message there
5. That exchange can then process the message in the normal way *including having an `alternate-exchange` setting of its own* which will be used if no bindings match the message